# How to make a listview show progressbar in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have an app where there is a list of goals, and each one has subgoals. When a subgoal is set as complete, I make the goal recalculate it's percentage of completion.

How can I make the listview show a progressbar to the side of each of the items?

Comment: Welcome to the Stack. Please review your last two questions which includes this one, Take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) from Help. See how some questions are effective, and how others are not and lead to question bans. We don't want that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your Adapter.

1. Find the "getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)" inside your adapter.
2. There will be a reference to the layout. For example:
   `view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);`
3. Add a progress bar to that layout (Control-click on listitem in Android Studio to get to the layout design). Name it, say, "progressBar"
4. Inside the same function (getView) add:
   `((ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar)).setProgress(p.completePercent());`, where `p` is the reference to your item.
5. Inside your item class add the `public int completePercent()` function to calculate the completeness depending on the subitems.